# Is it possible to splice in a 2nd temperature gauge?

Tags: coolant, mazda, temperature, gauges, mazda-6

This is a 2006 Mazda6 6 cylinder.

I want to install my Autometer temp gauge. Can I tie it into an existing wire or do I need to put in a second sensor? How do I tie it in?

Answer (score 2):

It should come with its own sensor - the sensor needs to be matched to the gauge...

If you connect the gauge to the existing sensor it may disrupt the signal to the ecu and cause all sorts of problems with the engine management.